# How to solve "No rule to make target "Edge.class", needed by "classes". Alto."

Tags: java, makefile

This is my Makefile

```
JC =javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class: $(JC) $*.java

CLASSES = \
   Edge.java \
   GraphGenerator.java \
   item.java \
   JavaQuest.java \
   mapa.java \
   Nodo.java \
   nodoCombate.java \
   nodoEvento.java \
   nodoInicial.java \
   nodoJefeFinal.java \
   nodoTienda.java \
   Personaje.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:\
   $(RM) *.class
```

I try to compile "JavaQuest" (main) but its show in console "No rule to make target "Edge.class", needed by "classes". Alto."
My files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
.java.class: $(JC) $*.java
```

This is defining a rule to build the target named, literally, `.java.class` with prerequisites `$(JC)` and `$*.java`.

You want either this:

```
.java.class:
        $(JC) $*.java
```

(where the indentation uses a TAB character) or this:

```
.java.class: ; $(JC) $*.java
```

(note the semicolon to separate the rule from the recipe).